# Grails: using "continue" (Java key word) in gsp page inside a <g:each> tag

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to skip few values inside a g:each tag. I want to implement the functionality of java "continue" key work. e.g

```
<g:each ......>
 <g:if....>
 // continue
 </g:if>
 //Some other logic
</g:each>
```

I hope question is clear.

Comment: do you really need a `continue` keyword, or just want to process only certain elements?

Comment: I want to skip certain elements form processing.

Comment: Why doesn't <g:else> work in that case?

Comment: you are rite i can use else but it will increase code repetition. 
If it is not possible i can use "else".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip certain elements, just use Groovy and `.findAll`.

For example, if you want to show only `items` with property `showVal > 10`:

```
<g:each in="${items.findAll { it.someVal > 10 }}">
 //Some logic
</g:each>
```

Or `<g:if>` / `<g:else>` if you don't want to touch `Groovy` inside your views.

Comment: Thanks. Quite similar to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `each` tag uses the Groovy `each` method and it invokes a Closure for each iteration. Closures are called like methods, so you must `return` from an `each` to skip that item; `continue` isn't valid because it's not a real Java loop.

So you can use a scriptlet to return if the condition is met:

```
<g:if....>
<% return %>
</g:if>
```